# twitter4j reach max length when send image with text in android

Tags: android, twitter

I used `twitter4j` to post tweet include image and text in android. My text has been truncate  to less than 140. But I wonder why the server response over 140 characters exception.
Here is my try:

```
 message = trimTweet(message); // guaranteed max length is less than 140
 StatusUpdate status = new StatusUpdate(message);

    if(bitmapUri != null){
    status.setMedia(new File(getRealPathFromURI(getApplicationContext(), bitmapUri)));
    }

  twitter.updateStatus(status);
```

The server response:

```
  10-23 19:18:00.842: E//NewsActivity.java:280(25288):  
  TwitterException{exceptionCode=[b2b52c28-11aaaacd], statusCode=403, 
  message=Status is over 140 characters., code=186, retryAfter=-1, 
  rateLimitStatus=null, version=3.0.4}
  10-23 19:18:00.842: E//NewsDetailActivity.java:280(25288):    at  twitter4j.internal.http.HttpClientImpl.request(HttpClientImpl.java:162)
 10-23 19:18:00.842: E//NewsDetailActivity.java:280(25288):     at twitter4j.internal.http.HttpClientWrapper.request(HttpClientWrapper.java:61)
 10-23 19:18:00.842: E//NewsDetailActivity.java:280(25288):     at twitter4j.internal.http.HttpClientWrapper.post(HttpClientWrapper.java:98)
```

From debug, I can see my tweet message less than 140 characters (sometime is 138 or 139). But when I try to send only 108 or 110 characters, it sent success. Then I wonder `twitter4j` add my image to tweet text. Is that right? 
How can I send image and text with only 140 characters?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Finally I figured out my problem. When adding URL or image, `Twitter` limit characters down to 118. That 's sound stupid, I think. From this link: http://mediacause.org/10-nonprofit-twitter-tips-140-characters/

> We all get tripped up by just how limiting 140 characters can be (it
>   sounds like a lot until you start typing). Add in a link or a photo,
>   and your character count for accompanying text is cut down to 118.
>   Keep this in mind when crafting tweets and include text that gets
>   straight to the point

**Update:** Thanks to @Aggressor, now twitter updated limit link depend on the URL that gets t.co wrapped.
The https steals away 23 characters(it was 21), so you have only 117 characters for text.
For non https url, you have 118 characters (wrapped url is 22).

**Https**:
[image]

**Http**:
[image]

Comment: I took me 2 hours to find this out on my own. I know that when you add an url to a tweet, it will be 22 chars long even if it is shorter than that, but who the hell knew you can't tweet from an app more than 118 characters? Their limitation webpage doesn't say a thing about it!

Comment: @Aggressor Why do you think that is should be 117? Have you tried it yet? I tested on twitter app and web site, they limit 118 characters if I use an url

Comment: It was failing for me at 118 sporadically. When I changed it to 117 it worked. http://www.geek.com/news/twitter-now-limits-tweets-to-117-characters-if-you-include-a-link-1540340/

Comment: @Aggressor Thanks, I update the answer. For https url, you have only 117 characters

Comment: That makes sense haha! Good deduction

Answer (score 0):

I found from the twitter documentation that while Tweets are still limited to 140 characters, the character counting model has evolved over time. Tweets are UTF-8 string content and any UTF-8 character counts as a single character. Strings that are understood as links, such as "http://twitter.com", "twitter.com", "twitter.com/twitterapi" will be automatically converted to t.co. t.co links represent a variant character count (currently "22" for HTTP-based links and "23" for HTTPS-based links). See [How Twitter wraps URLs with t.co](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/tco-url-wrapper/how-twitter-wrap-urls) for more information on how t.co plays a role in character counting. [Counting Characters](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/counting-characters) provides more details on character counting strategies.

Use [GET help/configuration](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/help/configuration) to programmatically keep track of t.co wrapping lengths. The fields "short_url_length" and "short_url_length_https" will indicate the current lengths.

Comment: But the problem is I don't face with url issue, I just want to upload text and image. Text is less than 140 character, and the image upload via binary stream, right? I don't know why image upload cost characters.

Comment: On the Twitter side images are added to the Tweet as links.